# Wordpress thumbnail grid expanding preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I found this great tutorial here: [codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/)

[Demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/)

but I can't figure out how to get it to work in Wordpress! I'm a beginner/intermediate with Javascript, but I'm really not sure how to plug it into Wordpress. The Wordpress Codex mentions putting the script directly into the post since it won't be used site-wide. Has anyone successfully been able to get this to work? Can you give me instructions on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it. By creating a short code in your functions.php file, you can include the js resources you need. Please note for this implementation, you must include the resources locally as defined on this line: `element.src = '/wp-content/themes/custom_name_space/js/$src';`

Or You can use some kind of plugin that lets you add custom js to a post.

```js
/** you will need to include this invocation in the source file. */
$(function() {
  Grid.init();
});
```

```html
<?php add_shortcode( 'custom_name_space_addJs', function ( $atts ) {
/**
 * create a javascript shortcode
 * shortcode takes an id attribute and src attribute
 * leaving src attribute blank will generate a 404 Error Code
 */

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
'id'=>'js-custom_name_space-script', 'src' => 'no-script.js', ), $atts ) ); return "
<script id='js-add-script-element'>
  (function(w, doc) {
    'use strict';

    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var element = doc.createElement('script');
        element.id = '$id';
        element.src = '/wp-content/themes/custom_name_space/js/$src';
        doc.body.appendChild(element);
      }
      /* Check for browser support of event handling capability */
    if (w.addEventListener) {
      w.addEventListener('load', downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    } else if (w.attachEvent) {
      w.attachEvent('onload', downloadJSAtOnload);
    } else {
      w.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
    }
  }(window, document));
</script>"; }); ?>



<!-- Then inside a wordpress post, write the needed HTML from the tutorial and use the short code -->

[custom_name_space_addJs id="thumb-grid" src="grid.js"]
```

Comment: <p>Thanks for the response! But I think I did something wrong..I got the white screen of death, and then I commented out the code I inserted in the functions.php file and now the site is up again. I have a few short follow-up questions:</p> <ul><li>Does the invocation code you gave to be placed in the grid.js file also need to be placed in the modernizr.custom.js file also? <code> $(function() {
  custom.modernizr.init();
});</code></li> <li>id and src attributes confused me a bit. Does it matter what name I chose for the id? and for the src i imagine its the same as the element.src?</li></ul>

Comment: Make sure the opening and closing php tags are in the appropriate places for your file. No, that code only needs to be placed at the end of the grid.js. The id attribute is arbitrary, but it should be unique and helpful for debugging so you can easily find the script tag. And the src attribute is the file name only, as I'm already pointing to a path within your theme, then the file name gets concatenated.